# Json sorting based on value

Tags: javascript, json

I have sample json, i need to sort based on the values using javascript/jquery.
I added example json code and expected output code in bellow.
For example with have this code :

```
   var json = {
    "users": {
        "metrics": {
            "e-f2e04fc7aa72": {
                "order": 5,
                "displayName": "User5"
            },
            "bb202c11-5d44-48a": {
                "order": 1,
                "displayName": "User2"
            },
            "a0d6e3afa2b5": {
                "order": 3,
                "displayName": "User3"
            },
            "46af13d22392856da": {
                "order": 4,
                "displayName": "User4"
            },
            "0c5f43cdd73b9cf623": {
                "order": 2,
                "displayName": "User2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I sort this json to be like this :

```
var json = {
    "users": {
        "metrics": {
            "bb202c11-5d44-48a": {
                "order": 1,
                "displayName": "User1"
            },
            "0c5f43cdd73b9cf623": {
                "order": 2,
                "displayName": "User2"
            },
            "a0d6e3afa2b5": {
                "order": 3,
                "displayName": "User3"
            },
            "46af13d22392856da": {
                "order": 4,
                "displayName": "User4"
            },
            "e-f2e04fc7aa72": {
                "order": 5,
                "displayName": "User5"
            },

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can **not** sort that, as there is no order in objects

Comment: you can sort array, not an object.

Comment: If you got this data from a database table before converting it to JSON, you could sort/order it in your SQL query itself using ORDER BY.

Comment: I get the json form another server and different project. so its not possible to change the json in backend . If anyother way its possible to change in frontend?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the properties of metrics, using e.g. `for .. in`, and create a list of users. Then it can be sorted.

```
var users = []
var metrics = json.users.metrics

for (var userId in metrics) {
    var user = metrics[userId];
    user["userId"] = userId;
    users.push(user);
}
```

In the format you expect, however, you cannot do it, as object properties cannot be sorted (as far as I know).

Comment: Its not possible to change the json format in backend. its any other way to change the json format in frontent?

Comment: I edited my answer, so you can create a list from the object you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort the object, but you can create a sorted list from it.

```
var metricsSorted = [];
for (var key in json.users.metrics) {
    var metric = json.users.metrics[key];
    metric.id = key;
    metricsSorted.push(metric);
}
metricsSorted.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order - b.order;
});
console.log(metricsSorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot sort an object, you can define your target json as array so it could be sorted.

Let's say, you can define you target json as :

```
var json = {
    "users": {
        "metrics": [
            {   "id": "bb202c11-5d44-48a",
                "order": 1,
                "displayName": "User1"
            },
            {   "id": "0c5f43cdd73b9cf623",
                "order": 2,
                "displayName": "User2"
            },
            {   "id": "a0d6e3afa2b5",
                "order": 3,
                "displayName": "User3"
            },
            {   "id": "46af13d22392856da",
                "order": 4,
                "displayName": "User4"
            },
            {   "id": "e-f2e04fc7aa72",
                "order": 5,
                "displayName": "User5"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And then you can use below code to sort your original json into it as below:

```
var metrics = []
for(var id in json.users.metrics){
    metrics.push({"id": id,"order":json.users.metrics[id].order,"displayName":json.users.metrics[id].displayName})
}
metrics.sort(function(a,b) { return a.order - b.order } );

json.users.metrics = metrics

//console.log(JSON.stringify(json))
```